# Continious functions on complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

The functions $$\frac{Re\,z}{|z|},\frac{z}{|z|}, \frac{Re \, z^2}{|z|^2}, \frac{zRe\, z}{|z|}$$
are all defined for $z \neq 0$. Which of them can be defined at the point $z = 0$
in such a way that the "extended" functions are continuous at $z = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the last one, because $\left|\frac z{|z|}\right|=1$ and therefore$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z\operatorname{Re}z}{|z|}=0,$$since $\lim_{z\to0}\operatorname{Re}z=0$.